# Declaration types for node_module repository with shared components

Tags: typescript, vue.js, typescript-typings

I've got private repository with components which are shared through other projects. This repository is fully written in javascript (Vue.js). I would like to add types definitions for those, who are using typescript. This shared repository doesn't have root file, all components are imported from their files (e.g. `import Button from 'shared/src/components/button'`. How can I include the types declarations in the shared repository, to use it in other applications? I tried to add `shared/src/components/button/index.d.ts` declaration file and add  `node_modules/shared` to `typeRoots` in `tsconfig.json`, but it doesn't work.